# Hide FabButton when floatingViewController appears. Cosmicmind/Material

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

I want to hide a FabButton everytime a floatingViewController appears and show it again when I close the view.

I tried hiding the FabButton itself with

```
self.menuButton.hidden = true
```

but there isn't a callback function when I close the floatingViewController so I dont have a way to un hide it.

I also tried setting the zPosition manually but the button is unaffected

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NavigationBarViewController has delegation methods for detecting the state of the floatingViewController. Set the delegate object,

```
navigationBarViewController?.delegate = self
```

Then try out the delegate methods:

```
extension AppNavigationBarViewController: NavigationBarViewControllerDelegate {
    /// Delegation method that executes when the floatingViewController will open.
func navigationBarViewControllerWillOpenFloatingViewController(navigationBarViewController: NavigationBarViewController) {
    print("Will Open")
}

    /// Delegation method that executes when the floatingViewController will close.
func navigationBarViewControllerWillCloseFloatingViewController(navigationBarViewController: NavigationBarViewController) {
    print("Will Close")
}

    /// Delegation method that executes when the floatingViewController did open.
func navigationBarViewControllerDidOpenFloatingViewController(navigationBarViewController: NavigationBarViewController) {
    print("Did Open")
}

    /// Delegation method that executes when the floatingViewController did close.
func navigationBarViewControllerDidCloseFloatingViewController(navigationBarViewController: NavigationBarViewController) {
    print("Did Close")
}
```

}

You should be able to use these methods to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. I'm new to swift and I didn't know the concept of delegates.

Comment: Great! :) You should mark the answer as accepted so future searches display that this has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

add this method to the FloatingViewController class

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
  let vc = ...assign to the viewcontroller that holds tour menu button 
  vc.menuButton.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: It worked, however I will stick to the delegate methods to have more readable code.